# Attrs argument doesn't work in URLColumn (Django-tables2)

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm trying to create a column which points to related `user`. I've decided to try `URLColumn`. Text attribute works correctly but when I try to add `href` url, it renders `<a href="None">Text</a>`.

Do you know where is the problem?

```
class PossiblePairsTable(tables.Table):
    customer_one = tables.URLColumn(attrs={'href':'somehref'},text=lambda x: x.reservation_one.customer.userprofile.display_name,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URLColumn` is meant to be used when the value of the column is a URL.

Try using the [`LinkColumn`](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#linkcolumn) instead.